# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch when using omniauth-google-oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I have signing in with Facebook working. I am now trying to get signing in with Google working.

I get Error: redirect_uri_mismatch and I can't figure out why.

I saw where somebody said to use omniauth-oauth2 v. 1.3.1 so I am.

My routes file includes:

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.4.1'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'
```

My omniauth.rb file is:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], info_fields: 'email,first_name,last_name'
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
  {
    :name => "google",
    :scope => "email, profile, plus.me, http://gdata.youtube.com",
    :prompt => "select_account",
    :image_aspect_ratio => "square",
    :image_size => 50
  }
end
```

I have taken the error message

`The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client`

and copied the uri, and then gone into the credientials page for the google api,and then added that exact uri as an Authorized Redirect URI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this answer it worked with me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41466634/1770571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [console.developers.google.com](http://console.developers.google.com.). Enter your app’s URL plus

```
“/auth/google_oauth2/callback”
```

in “Authorized redirect URIs field. So It should be:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback
```

Comment: When I do that, I get: No route matches [GET] "/auth/google_oauth2"

Comment: My routes.rb includes: get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create_omniauth'

Comment: From a terminal, I can run "curl localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback" and it finds that route.  But if I try it without the /callback, it doesn't.  It's almost like google is not sending back /callback.

Comment: Well, I fixed it. I did what you said @HasmukhRathod, even though I had tried it before. It didn't fix it, but then I tried google_oauth2 section in my omniauth.rb file.  It fixed it. I ended up figuring out that it was the :name => "google" thing that was the problem.  When I did what Hasmukh Rathod said, and then got rid of the name key, it worked! Hooray!

Comment: @atarihomestar Post this comment as an answer and accept THAT one.