# redirect_uri_mismatch. Login with Google using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, omniauth-google-oauth2

I'm trying to add Google Login to my app using `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem.

I have created the client Id and secret in `console.developers.google.com` and added redirect_uri as follows.

[image]

routes.rb

```
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'people#socialmedialogin',:as => :callback
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.4.0'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
```

I am facing the problem in signing in. It is authenticating with Google and fails to redirect. Error is as follows.

```
redirect_uri_mismatch: { "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch" }

Extracted source (around line #113):

  when 400..599
    error = Error.new(response)
    raise(error) if opts.fetch(:raise_errors, options[:raise_errors])
    response.error = error
    response
  else
    .....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to downgrade the gem (could be compatibility problem) :

```
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'
```